# Dragonfly cache location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, dragonfly-gem

Does anyone know the location of the rails image gem dragonfly's cache.  I don't want to have to regenerate all the different sized versions of images each time I deploy.

I already keep the original files in shared and symlink them to each deploy, but can't work out where the resized versions are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dragonfly does not store resized images on disk, which is part of its appeal; it generates resized versions of the image on demand. This is very flexible, but it means that you could take a nasty performance hit if you're always serving images from your Rails processes. You should cache them using something like Varnish or a CDN for best performance.

Comment: Thanks for the info... Better look at getting something set up!

Answer (score 0):

Actually Dragonfly does provide a to_file() method so you can definitely cache your images. If you are lazy like me and want to do it the easy way, check out the handy **[dragonfly_helper](https://github.com/gbarillot/dragonfly_helper)**